# How to get DD-MM-YYYY format date

Tags: react-native

I'm using Parse database. I store date format. when using console i get this format :  `Tue Jul 18 2017 15:46:47 GMT+0100 (CET)`
 I want to get this format : 18-07-2017. 
Any idea please

Answer (score 18):

It can be done by using following code:

```
let today = new Date();

let date=today.getDate() + "-"+ parseInt(today.getMonth()+1) +"-"+today.getFullYear();

console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 4):

The moment library is awesome for all action/formatting that you want to do on date.

Have a look: https://momentjs.com/

You should do something like this:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'

const yourDate = new Date()
const NewDate = moment(yourDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: when trying 'console.log("date", NewDate)' nothing appears

Comment: Can you show us what exactly in sequence you are writing into the console? I also assume the console you mean is the chrome console?

Comment: Also did you install moment? npm install moment

Comment: I installed  moment  and  imported it.  Ten in my componentDidMount function  i put this code : `const yourDate = new Date();  
const NewDate = moment(yourDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')   ; console.log("my text", NewDate) ;`

Comment: the console in terminal i mean

Comment: Does: console.log(moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")) print something?

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to get the result that you want in react-native like this:

> import moment from 'moment'; // Import momentjs -->
> https://momentjs.com
>
> const maxDate = moment(new Date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format(); //
> 15-11-2017T11:17:30+01:00

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: how to remove time from the converted date?

Comment: @devedv you can try 

const formatteddate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: @Fabzien Thanks! it helped me.

Answer (score 3):

This resolved formatted my date into `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
import moment from 'moment';

let date = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import moment from 'moment';

var NewDate= moment(new Date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format();
NewDate=NewDate.split('T')[0];
```

Comment: @Nacho Justicia Ramos already provide this answer