# Formating date in React/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some dates fetched from an API. However I would like to format them in a more presentable manner.
They currently display like so `1972-08-24` however I would like to display them as YEAR,MONTH. How would I do this?

Current code:
`<p className='available'>Available: {movie.release_date}</p>`

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547166/how-to-get-dd-mm-yyyy-format-date

Answer (score 1):

check out [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
var moment = require('moment');

var yourDate = new Date('1972-08-24')
var formattedDate = moment(yourDate).format('YYYY, MMMM');
```